# Disable a specific case provided by cindent when enter a colon `:`

Tags: vimrc

As title. What I have currently after entering `:` after the `std`:

```cpp
  std::memset(tempArr, 0, MAX_LEN_CASE*sizeof(int));
  for (int i=0; i<MAX_LEN_CASE; ++i) {
std:
  }
```

What I expect is:

```cpp
  std::memset(tempArr, 0, MAX_LEN_CASE*sizeof(int));
  for (int i=0; i<MAX_LEN_CASE; ++i) {
    std:
  }
```

If I enter the second `:` after the first one I will get the expected behaviour:

```cpp
  std::memset(tempArr, 0, MAX_LEN_CASE*sizeof(int));
  for (int i=0; i<MAX_LEN_CASE; ++i) {
    std::
  }
```

I'm using Neovim but I found that this is also reproducible in Vim. Can anyone tell me how to disable it or maybe explain what could be the intent of this design?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line into `after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
setlocal cinkeys-=:
```